# sending email using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Am trying to send an email in codeigniter. I first created an independent function in the model and it's corespondent in the controller and it worked very well. The email was sent and received in both yahoo and gmail. However when I tried to use the same code in another function where am selection the email address (recipient) from the database, it gives me a message that email successfully sent but it actually doesn't deliver to yahoo or gmail. what could be the problem?
It' not even delivering into the spam/bulk mail.

the codes for the one that worked and that that failed are bellow.

the model function is

```
function sendMail()
{
   $to = "mymail@yahoo.com"; 
       $subject = "My Sublect"; 
       $messagetext= "stop distubbing me and work!";
       $config=array(
      'protocol'=>'smtp',
      'smtp_host'=>'mail.mydomail.co.ug',
      'smtp_port'=>25,
      'smtp_user'=>'myname@mydomail.co.ug',
      'smtp_pass'=>'mypass'
    );
    $this->load->library("email",$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from("myname@mydomail.co.ug","Joyce");
    $this->email->to($to); 
    $this->email->subject($subject); 
    $this->email->message($messagetext); 
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "Mail send successfully!";
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

the controller fcn

```
function sendmail()
{
    $this->load->model('customer_model');
    $this->customer_model->sendMail();
}
```

However the one that failed to work is bellow

```
function customer()
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array(
              'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
              'contact'=>$this->input->post('contact'),
              'entity'=>$this->input->post('entity'),
              'sector'=>$this->input->post('sector'),
              'inquiry'=>$this->input->post('inquiry'),
         'nature_of_inquiry'=>$this->input->post('nature_of_inquiry'),
          'status'=>$this->input->post('status'),

                );
    $this->db->insert('customers',$data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $refno = date('d/m/Y').'-C'.str_pad($id, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

$this->db->query("UPDATE customers set refno = '".$refno."' WHERE id = '".$id."'"); 

$query=$this->db->query("select entity,name,status,contact from customers where id ='".$id."'");
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $entity = $row->entity;
    $phone = $row->contact;
    $name = $row->name;
    $status = $row->status;
}   

$query1=$this->db->query("select phone, email from services where entity = '".$entity."'");
     foreach ($query1->result() as $row)
{

    $to = $row->email;
}   
    $sms ="Dear $name, your request/compaint has been $status";
    //$emailtext ="yo company has been refferenced by servicecops.";
   //$this->sendSMS(test,$phone,$sms);
   //$subject = "Servicecops Reminder";
   $config=array(
      'protocol'=>'smtp',
      'smtp_host'=>'mail.mydomain.co.ug',
      'smtp_port'=>25,
      'smtp_user'=>'myname@mydomain.co.ug',
      'smtp_pass'=>'mypass',
      'mailtype'=>'html'
    );
    $this->load->library("email",$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from("myname@mydomain.co.ug","Joyce");
    $this->email->to($to); 
    $this->email->subject("my subject"); 
    $this->email->message("yo company has been refferenced by me"); 
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "Mail send successfully!";
        echo $to;
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

    return $this;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post some code samples as well as the error message you are getting.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you aren't using the CI mail class? We also need to see some code, and if you've checked the spam boxes of the failed sends to see if there's a problem noted in the mail headers.

Comment: Please take your time when asking questions! Provide some code and what have you tried!

Comment: A code example would do ;-)

Answer (score 4):

First try to check if you are fetching the emails well from database. If yes then check in the spam. That would solve the problem I guess.

Comment: Am fetching the email well from the database because i tried to print it and it came. the first code which worked is bellow.

Comment: Did you check in the spam or junk mail? some times it goes into spam or junk.

Comment: yes i Did check but there is no mail at all. have edited and put the code.

Answer (score 1):

Guys i have discovered the problem. I had defined the email library twice in the same function that's why messages where not reaching yahoo and gmail inbox. at the begining of the function, i had put. $this->load->library('email'); and this in the midle. $this->load->library("email",$config);

Answer (score 0):

Most of the mails getting spam if you use IP address while running with the URL(ex: 123.117.116.27/test/email/) instead of domain name. So check with spam folder.

Comment: Spam folder doesn't have any mail as well.

Comment: Guys i have discovered the problem. I had defined the email library twice in the same function that's why messages where not reaching yahoo and gmail inbox. at the begining of the function, i had put. $this->load->library('email'); and this in the midle. $this->load->library("email",$config);